# Angular Fullstack + CORS: XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, cors

I have been pulling my hair on this one.

I used the [yeoman generator angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) to create a small angular app on a nodeJS server with Express. I am using a remote service so no api server side calls are written within my app.

Factory:

```
   var offerServiceURL = "https://www.example.com";
    angular.module("services", ['ngResource'])
    .factory('offerService', function($resource) {
        return $resource(offerServiceURL+'/offers/service/:action/:param1',
        {
            action: '@action'
        },
        {

            getOfferEligibility : {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {action:'get-offer-eligibility'}
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, offerService){
   offerService.getOfferEligibility($scope.user, function(data){
         if(data.status == "SUCCESS"){
           ....
         }    
   })
})
```

Chrome gives me a generic error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://example.com/offers/service/get-offer-eligibility. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost.digitalink.com:9000' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

The request header makes it to OPTIONS with the correct info:

> Request Method:OPTIONS Status Code:200 OK Response Headers view source
>   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers:content-type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost.digitalink.com:9000

However it breaks at POST and does not have the correct headers.

In fact, other people on my team are able to successfully access the service from their local machines using the same angular factory running on a webpage. I compared my headers with the headers on a successful POST. I am missing the Access-Control headers on my POST Request.

The only discrepancy I can think of is they are trying from Java apps with port 8080. Does that make a difference? Any insight will be helpful!

Comment: "In theory, this should work." — Have you looked at the headers returned? Have you checked that they are correct?

Comment: "other people on my team are able to successfully access the service from different IPs without hitting any CORS issues" — Are they doing that from JavaScript running in a web page?

Comment: btw, the https://example.com/offers/service/get-offer-eligibility you've mentioned returns 404.

Comment: @incarnate — That's because example.com is used for example URLs. The real URL is presumably on a private development network.

Comment: The CORS module for node works great, I would just install that. I don't know how that yeoman generator has it setup, but its possible they dont have any CORS setup on the server, or missed allowing POSTs. I've had CORS work/not work depending on the browser i've used. That could explain why your team members dont have problems. Either way, you should enable CORS fully on your server.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses, sorry my question is unclear, i will update accordingly. @Quentin, I did look at the headers returned and on the OPTIONS request they are correct but in the POST request they are missing all the Access-Control Headers. Other people on my team are doing it using AngularJS running on a web page.

Comment: @ribsies, I did add the cors module but I did not see any difference. I am not making any server side api calls using express but just calling the remote service from the angular factory.

Comment: maybe including your server side code for this would help

Comment: Browsers like Chrome and Firefox usually block requests from a server to localhost. Run Chrome with Web Security disabled and see if it works. This solved a similar issue I had for a few days. If you're on Mac, command is: open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security

Comment: @austinthedeveloper that was really helpful tip thanks! now i get an error like this: {"systemerror":"systemerror"}

Comment: This is one of those Homer Simpson situations (D'OH) - the service didn't like my data. There is still an issue with the server side code because if the request is bad CORS headers should still be returned with at least an error message.  Thanks to all for their input!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was not related to CORS problems on the client side. The answer is that the service did not like my data. If the data was bad, the API was returning bad CORS headers instead of sending a response that the data was bad.

Answer (score 0):

you can enable CORS in you app using expressjs app by using cors module of expressjs.

**Installation**

```
npm install cors
```

**Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)**

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

for more details go to https://github.com/expressjs/cors